# Resource files as repositories in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have a system that needs compute some operations based on complex formulas. Some of them require to choose values based on some table data (like an excel). Coding this table data is a mess, so I have decided to maintain de data tables in csv files and search their values when I need. This data not represent any entity, so I have the doubt if this files have to be coded as a DDD repository.
The only reason to use csv files is for code clarity. If I have to code each files like a repository interface and inject them to entity each time that I have to compute something, the code lose readability.
On the other hand, in DDD entities have to be independent of any architecture implementation. Doing this I'm coupling entities with an "external resource".

Answer (score 1):

Putting CSV reading code in a repository is exactly what you should do.  I don’t understand the part about this making the code less readable – it should make things more readable because there would be a single method call on a repository whose purpose is well known.

Using a repository has other advantages as well.  For unit tests you do not have to create CSV files specifically for a particular test.  Instead you can mock the repository to return any value necessary for the test.  Also, should the implementation of that data change at some point in the future it will be much easier to update to the new data source if the code is in a repository.